# SceneKit shadows on wall

Tags: ios, swift, shadow, scenekit, lighting

I have a cube, a wall and two lightNodes in my SceneKit application and I would like to make the cube throw a shadow onto the wall.

My lightNodes are here:

```
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeSpot
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)
    lightNode.castsShadow = true
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    ambientLightNode.castsShadow = true
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
```

This is my wall:

```
    var wall = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 400, height: 100, length: 4, chamferRadius: 0))
    wall.geometry?.firstMaterial!.emission.contents = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    wall.geometry?.firstMaterial!.doubleSided = false
    wall.castsShadow = true
    wall.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -5)
    wall.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(wall)
```

As you can see all of the nodes (including the cube) have the property to cast shadow, since it is `true`.

How does it come that there is no shadow on the wall?

Answer (score 4):

same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785271/scenekit-lighting-and-casting-shadows)? You have to set `castsShadow` on the light (instead of on the node that holds the light).

Also note that omnidirectional and ambient lights can *not* cast shadows. Only directional and spot lights can.

Comment: Hm, made the `Omni-LightNode` to a `Spot` one but it still does not cast any shadows... :/

Comment: If you make it a spot, ensure it points at the wall. e.g. `let lightConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: wall); lightNode.constraints = [lightConstraint]`

Comment: Are there special circumstances needed to trigger shadows with directional lights? We can only seem to generate shadows with spot lights.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this is the case, but I was having a similar issue and found that setting the `light`'s `shadowMode` to `SCNShadowModeDeferred` fixed it.