# Cast shadow on all nodes SCNLight

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to cast a short dark shadow from the left of the scene. My light settings are the following:

```
func setupLights() {

    // Create shadow
    let spotLight = SCNLight()
    spotLight.type = SCNLightTypeSpot
    spotLight.spotInnerAngle = 30.0
    spotLight.spotOuterAngle = 80.0
    spotLight.castsShadow = true
    let spotLightNode = SCNNode()
    spotLightNode.light = spotLight
    spotLightNode.position = SCNVector3(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)
    rootNode.addChildNode(spotLightNode)

    // Create ambient light
    let ambientLight = SCNLight()
    ambientLight.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLight.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.name = "AmbientLight"
    ambientLightNode.light = ambientLight
    ambientLightNode.castsShadow = true
    rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // Create an omni-directional light
    let omniLight = SCNLight()
    omniLight.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    omniLight.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let omniLightNode = SCNNode()
    omniLightNode.name = "OmniLight"
    omniLightNode.light = omniLight
    omniLightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -10.0, y: 20, z: 10.0)
    omniLightNode.castsShadow = true
    rootNode.addChildNode(omniLightNode)
}
```

With this code I have a bright scene with some very light and long shadow not coming from the left. I tried to alter the position which currently is SCNVector3(1.5, 1.5, 1.5), however whichever other position I put, the shadow just disappears. Any ideas?

Comment: It's worth noting that the default for [`zFar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNLight_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNLight/zFar), the maximum distance between light and object that will produce a shadow is 1.0. Moving the position of the spot light may mean you exceed this distance, and end up with no shadow as a result.

Having the omni, ambient, and spot lights may be a bit much for the scene. For a "dark shadow" I'd try using an ambient light with a grey colour, and just the spot light (no omni).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want directional light on all parts of the scene, use `SCNLightTypeSpot` for your light's `type`. Or maybe `SCNLightTypeDirectional`.

Per documentation for `SCNLight.castsShadow:`

> Geometries illuminated by the light cast shadows only if the value of this property is YES and the type property of the light is SCNLightTypeSpot. The default value is NO.

However, @mnuages states in [SceneKit shadows on wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827311/scenekit-shadows-on-wall) that directional lights can cast shadows.