# How to change color of dark spots in SceneKit?

Tags: scenekit, scnlight

How to change color of the area where light doesn't reach?

By default it's black, so how can I make it white for example? I couldn't find it, if its duplicate, please let me know how to form my question in order to find correct answer!

Thank you in advance

Comment: This looks like the same question you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049543/how-to-change-shadow-color-in-scenekit. It is marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785271/scenekit-lighting-and-casting-shadows. Instead of repeating the question, go back to your original and make it more precise.

Comment: @HalMueller this isn't a duplicate of that spot lighting issue. He's struggling to find how to do ambient lighting.

Answer (score 2):

The "color of the are where light doesn't reach" demonstrates your problem, you have no light influencing your scene at this point. In any space/place where light doesn't reach, there is no colour, only blackness.

Here are the common ways of addressing 3D lighting:

**1. Add more lights to places that create your ideal lighting**

This is an artistic process, time consuming and arduous to get "just so". But it gets the best effects and the best atmosphere, generally speaking.

### or...

**2. Use an ambient light in your scene to light everything**

When starting out, in 3D, there's so much to master that simply throwing in an ambient light and getting on with other work towards your goal is probably a good workflow. Work on artistic light last, use ambient lighting until then: https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnlight.lighttype/1522769-ambient

---

**Caveat:**
Ambient lights will likely solve your problem of the dark edges, but will also wash out a lot of your existing shadows.

Answer (score 0):

SCNLight has a property for changing the color of shadows. Here's a link to the page for more info. If you have any other questions, let me know, hopefully this helps.

[SCNLight.shadowColor Link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnlight/1522864-shadowcolor)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the shading mode to `Constant` if you don't want a node to be affected by shading (making it therefore dark):

[image]